# React Native File Viewer not working in Production

Tags: react-native

i am using react-native-file-viewer for opening the file for view my application is working find in development mode, but is stuck on the splash screen while i am using this sin production mode. it works fine without using the file viewer.

i am using react native with typescript (Ejected from expo)

Comment: Take a look at the console, maybe there's an error.

Comment: If you can't find the error in the production, maybe setup sentry would be helpful to you.

Comment: in production mode not loging any thing

Comment: i want to open pdf,docx file to preview. if you can suggest any other library I can try.

Comment: i have setup sentry but not find anything